# Dealing with large amount of conditionals in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a math flashcard game, where you can change the options of the game, such as math operator, time, difficulty, and I want to avoid using a mass amount of if statements, but im not sure how to go about doing this.

```
if optionsScreen.flashcardtype == '*' and optionsScreen.flashcarddifficulty == "classical":
            optionsScreen.explanationtitle = "Classical -"
            optionsScreen.explanation = "Times tables up to the 15's! A classical challenge!"
            optionsScreen.flashcarddifficultyint1 = 1
            optionsScreen.flashcarddifficultyint2 = 15
        if optionsScreen.flashcardtype == '/' and optionsScreen.flashcarddifficulty == "classical":
            optionsScreen.explanationtitle = "Classical -"
            optionsScreen.explanation = "Divide numbers up to 50's! A classical challenge!"
            optionsScreen.flashcarddifficultyint1 = 1
            optionsScreen.flashcarddifficultyint2 = 50
        if optionsScreen.flashcardtype == '-' and optionsScreen.flashcarddifficulty == "classical":
            optionsScreen.explanationtitle = "Classical -"
            optionsScreen.explanation = "Subtract up to the 70's! A classical challenge!"
            optionsScreen.flashcarddifficultyint1 = 1
            optionsScreen.flashcarddifficultyint2 = 79
        if optionsScreen.flashcardtype == '+' and optionsScreen.flashcarddifficulty == "classical":
            optionsScreen.explanationtitle = "Classical -"
            optionsScreen.explanation = "Addition up to the 70's! A classical challenge!"
            optionsScreen.flashcarddifficultyint1 = 1
            optionsScreen.flashcarddifficultyint2 = 79
```

This is what I have right now, this is one area of code for the change of the difficulty to "classical", with the different operators. Is there anyway to avoid a large amount of if statements like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question that is really asking for an opinion, so may not be an appropriate question. However, keep in mind that a dictionary can be used as a lookup table, and keys can be tuples. So you can just make a compact table representation and a lookup function. Since dictionaries can also be inherited from, you might also make a special class for it.

Here's an example.

```py
# (cardtype, difficulty) -> (title, explanation, difficulty1, difficulty2)
MAP = {
    ("/", "classical"): ("Classical -", "Divide numbers up to 50's! A classical challenge!", 1, 50),
    ("-", "classical"): ("Classical -", "Subtract up to the 70's! A classical challenge!", 1, 79),
}  # ...


def get_info(card_type, difficulty):
    return MAP.get((card_type, difficulty), (None, None, None, None))


title, explanation, difficulty1, difficulty2 = get_info("/", "classical")
print(title, explanation, difficulty1, difficulty2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely try to see what statements can be `clubbed together` to make the code a little more readable. Example

```py
if conditionA and conditionZ:
    ...
if conditionB and conditionZ:
    ...
if conditionC and conditionZ:
    ...
```

can be re-writen as

```py
if conditionZ:
    if conditionA:
        ...
    if conditionB:
        ...
    if conditionC
```

if this still feels like a lot of text to understand, I would suggest you break it down further,

```py
def handle_conditionZ():
    ...

if conditionZ:
    handle_conditionZ()
```

which if you apply to your code would look something like,

```py
def setOptionsScreen(optionsScreen, explanation: str, difficultyInt1: int, difficultyInt2: int):
        optionsScreen.explanation = explanation
        optionsScreen.flashcarddifficultyint1 = difficultyInt1
        optionsScreen.flashcarddifficultyint2 = difficultyInt2

def handle_classical(optionsScreen):
    if optionsScreen.flashcardtype == '*':
        setOptionsScreen(
            optionsScreen=optionsScreen, 
            explanation="Times tables up to the 15's! A classical challenge!", 
            difficultyInt1=1, difficultyInt2=15)
    if optionsScreen.flashcardtype == '/':
        setOptionsScreen(
            optionsScreen=optionsScreen, 
            explanation="Times tables up to the 15's! A classical challenge!", 
            difficultyInt1=1, difficultyInt2=15)
    if optionsScreen.flashcardtype == '-':
        setOptionsScreen(
            optionsScreen=optionsScreen, 
            explanation="Times tables up to the 15's! A classical challenge!", 
            difficultyInt1=1, difficultyInt2=15)
    if optionsScreen.flashcardtype == '+':
        setOptionsScreen(
            optionsScreen=optionsScreen, 
            explanation="Times tables up to the 15's! A classical challenge!", 
            difficultyInt1=1, difficultyInt2=15)

if optionsScreen.flashcarddifficulty == "classical":
    optionsScreen.explanation = "Classical - "
    handle_classical(optionsScreen)
```